# How to change a keycode using setkeycodes

Tags: xorg, keyboard, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad Edge E130 running Sabayon (a Gentoo-based distro), and I'm fighting the well-know bug **Xorg 255 keycodes limit**.

My laptop has the Fn+F4 hotkey for *Mic Mute/Unmute*. This is the problem:

- `showkey -k` shows keycode **248** on Fn+F4 keypress
- `showkey -s` shows nothing on keypress
- `xev` shows nothing on keypress (because 248+8 [added by kernel] is bigger than 255)

If a key has a keycode, it must have a scancode too. With [getscancodes](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/dl-getscancodes.html) program indeed I got 26 as scancode:

```
# ./Sabayon/getscancodes/getscancodes /dev/input/event6 
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x17aa product 0x5054 version 0x4101
Input device name: "ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
26 (0x1a)
26 (0x1a)
```

According to [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1536096#post1536096) thread, my guess is simply to change the keycode of the hotkey with a smaller, unused one. For example 120 seems to be unused according to my `$ xmodmap -pke`

I have tried with

```
# setkeycodes 0x1a 120
```

but without success, the keycode is always 248 checking with `showkey`.

How is the proper way to change keycodes?

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `showkey` to know your key scancode:

   ```
   $ sudo showkey -s
   0xe0 0xXX
   ```
2. Kernel will add 8 to you code, use `112` instead `120`:

   ```
   $ sudo setkeycodes e0XX 112
   ```
3. Use `xmodmap` to make your key report `XF86AudioMute` keysym:

   ```
   $ xmodmap -e "keycode 120 = XF86AudioMute"
   ```
4. *Optional*. Press you key when creating shortcut to what you want in the settings of your DE.

Comment: Actually I switched to Debian Sid and `Fn+F4` works out of the box here (maybe just because I have a newer kernel version). But thank you anyway, your solution looks good and I hope will help other people.

Comment: This does not work for USB keyboards, because `setkeycodes` does not support them. If the system has udev, the keys can be remapped by adding a custom entry to the hardware database. Example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384566/245377

Comment: Why subtract 8? Do you have chapter and verse?

Comment: Note if you _are_ trying to use `showkey -s`: it may not report real raw scancodes for use with `setkeycodes`; as a sanity check, compare the resulting keycodes (shown by `showkey` [`-k`]) with what keycode the table for the existing mapping shown by `getkeycodes` says should be produced for the scancode you got from `showkey -s`.

Comment: How to get the scancode if `sudo showkey -s` doesn't return anything? I'm also in the same scenario, `showkey -k` returns 248 for me.

Answer (score 1):

What I want to do is that when the "pause" button is pressed, the character "k" is printed. The problem is that the "pause" button has no scan code (`showkey -s` does not work). I solved this problem like this:

1. Switch to the console
2. Use `showkey -k` to know keycode of "pause" button (425 in my case)

```
$ showkey -k
keycode 425 press
keycode 425 release
```

3. Use `getkeycodes` to get a table of mapping keycodes to scancodes

```
e0 68:  128 159 158 157 155 226 225 224
e0 70:    0 192 193 149 148 425 116   0
e0 78:  464 148   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

4. In this table find the scancode associated with keycode 425 (e075 in my case)
5. Switch back to X
6. Use `xmodmap -pke` to find keycode you need (you can also modify them) (45 in my case)

```
keycode  45 = k K Cyrillic_el Cyrillic_EL k K
```

7. Subtract 8 to get kernel keycode (45 - 8 = 37)
8. Use `setkeycodes` to add association between raw scancode e075 and kernel keycode 37

```
sudo setkeycodes e075 37
```

9. Test it. It should work

Answer (score 0):

step 1: `xmodmap -pke` will list you keycodes

step 2: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 51 = backslash bar'` will change that keycode to backslash